# Selecting elements with special characters in the ID

Tags: jquery, html

In html code I am using code 
`<input type = "text" id = "abc@def.com">` to get text 
now it need to get its value which is entered in text field. I am using jquery to do that:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( ".bid" ).click( function() {
        idVal = this.id
        bidID = "#" + idVal + "bid"
        spanID = "#" + idVal + "cbid"
        bidValue = $(bidID).val();

        alert(idVal)
        alert(bidID)
        alert(bidValue) //this alert says undefined
        $( spanID ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '{% url online_machines %}?id=' + idVal + '&bidvalue=' + bidValue);
    });
});
```

By doing this i get the value error undefined. 
I tried to remove  special characters from the id to get its value. But I need the id with special characters. How can
I get its value using jquery ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try escaping it:

```
$('#abc\\@def.com').val();
```

First paragraph of http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I believe that would be $('#abc\\@def\\.com')

Answer (score 38):

Instead of trying for ID using #, try this to match attribute like this,

```
$('[id=ID]')
```

or

```
$('[id='+ID+']')
```

so instead of

```
bidID = "#" + idVal + "bid"
```

you can try

```
bidID = "[id=" + idVal + "bid]"
```

Comment: In some cases you might need to do it like this: $("[id='ID']")

Comment: This might not work: $('[id='+ID+']') you should put `$('[id="'+ID+'"]')`
Value of id should be inside quotes

Answer (score 13):

It looks like JQuery has a useful method for this as of version 3 called `escapeSelector`.

`$('#' + $.escapeSelector(my_id_with_special_chars));`

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

Answer (score 6):

`$(document.getElementById('abc@def.com'))` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function CSS.escape() to select that DOM element.
In your case for the id abc@def.com you can use the below code.

```
$("#" + CSS.escape('abc@def.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a shot at this, not 100% on whether this is what you're after. Let me know:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".bid").click(function() {
        idVal = $(this).attr('id');
        bidID = "#" + idVal + "bid";
        spanID = "#" + idVal + "cbid";
        bidValue = bidID.val();

        alert(idVal);
        alert(bidID);
        alert(bidValue);
        spanID.html('&nbsp;').load('{% url online_machines %}?id=' + idVal + '&bidvalue=' + bidValue);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution below worked for me, it is pretty clean:

```
//your HTML id has special characters: 
var option= "Some option with (parenthesis or @ )";
//use this type of jquery query:
$(`[id="order_${option}"]`).prop('checked',true)
```