# jQuery doesn't get elements with IDs as valid email addresses

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [special characters in id of html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675454/special-characters-in-id-of-html-tags)

I have a DIV with the id as email:

```
<div id="example@example.com">This is blah blah text</div>
```

Now with jQuery, I want to select that DIV and hide it:

```
$('#example@example.com').hide();
```

And that's not working!

Since I'm generating these DIVs dynamicly and I don't want to query the db again for the real row IDs, I'm gonna use the email addresses as IDs, and I can't do it...

Any solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the HTML 4.01 spec: `ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).` While in HTML5 you could use that for ID, you really want it to be backwards compatible. You could store emails in `data-email="info@example.com"`

Comment: You should store this email address in the `rel` attribute or in `$.data`.

Comment: @MihaRekar the HTML5 spec says otherwise - the only illegal character is a space.

Comment: @Alnitak yup, but you really want it to be backward compatible, don't you? :P I'll edit my comment...

Comment: @MihaRekar I'm merely pointing out that for current values of "the spec" your assertion is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "example@example.com" as an html element's id, instead use data attribute like this

```
<div data-id="example@example.com">
</div>
```

Then use jQuery to select it like this

```
$('div[data-id="example@example.com"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that IDs such as this are only legal in HTML5.

To use those IDs as selectors in jQuery you must escape the special characters:

```
$('#example\\@example.com').hide();
```

Comment: then this might hide the other divs, since the divs might have IDs as example@exampleONE.com, and example@exampleTWO.com, then my jquery will hide both of them, this is wrong...

Comment: @behz4d: Then just change your selector to match those examples?

Answer (score 0):

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \

your id is not valid under the html4.1 it must follow the rule below

1. Must contain at least one character
2. Must not contain any space characters
3. In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

above from http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

but if you are using the heml5 than below are valid

```
<div id="#">Foo.
<div id="##">Bar.
<div id="♥">Baz.
<div id="©">Inga.
<div id="{}">Lorem.
<div id="“‘’”">Ipsum.
<div id="⌘⌥">Dolor.
<div id="{}">Sit.
<div id="[attr=value]">Amet.
<div id="++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.">Hello world!
```

to use this you need to escape these thing by `\\` like `$('#example\\@example.com')`