# Using & in CSS selectors

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a div with id as `masterResourceFor_R&D`. But when I use this ID in jQuery to select this `div` and put a click function on it, it doesn't work. I think the problem is because of the symbol `&` in ID. I do not have any option to rename the ID.

How can I use this ID in jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [special characters in id of html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675454/special-characters-in-id-of-html-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore using special characters as id's and class names, change it if you can, if you can't and you want to solve <s>[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ztw4Y/1/)</s> mess, you need to escape that character

```
#masterResourceFor_R\&D {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ztw4Y/)

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters)

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Answer (score 5):

You can escape the character using backslashes (`\`).

#### CSS

```css
#masterResourceFor_R\&D { ... }
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#masterResourceFor_R\\&D');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNS5d/).

Comment: +1 for both examples for clarity. @ OP: The only reason for the two backslashes in the second example is that in a string in JavaScript, backslash has a special meaning: Take the next character literally. So in a string, `\\` is one actual backslash.

Answer (score 2):

escape it with `\`

```
$('#masterResourceFor_R\\&D')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nRqg7/)