# Jquery : Can't find the bug, probably something with the ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a planning that is an HTML table where each cell has an ID built on DateTime format. Then I send a JSON with booked time-slots from django model and try to change the class of the cells with the corresponding ID with Jquery.

delivery_planning.js :

```
dates = booked_json.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
booked_dates = JSON.parse(dates);
count = booked_dates.length-1;

for (i=0; i<=count; i++) {
    var date_id = "#" + booked_dates[i];
    $(date_id).toggleClass("available unavailable");
    console.log(date_id); 
};
```

console.log() shows me that the ID are at good format :

```
#2018-09-15_13:30:00
```

and when I inspect the cells in firefox I have the same ID format :

```
td#2018-09-15_13:30:00.available
```

Can anyone see why the class is not changing? I've tried several variations in the format with no results. I can add views.py and template.html to show the construction of IDs if needed.

Comment: `booked_json.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');` <- that's a really bad idea. If you need to replace HTML entities, do it **after** you parse the JSON

Comment: In general, not a big fan of using these as ID's. But if you want to use them you probably just need to escape the right chars: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: Hmm, not sure what happened to the duplicate close vote but here it is again ~ Possible duplicate of [special characters in id of html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6675454/283366)

Comment: Yeah this post is kind of the same issue but I'm not sure i would have recognized it. Thanks anyways :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query doesn't select any element as the selector contains `:` character. It has a special meaning for jQuery selector engine. You either need to escape the `:` chars:

```
$('#2018-09-15_13\\:30\\:00')
```

Or better, use `document.getElementById`:

```
$(document.getElementById(booked_dates[i])).toggleClass('...')
```

Comment: I assume you re-opened this question, but why? This exact answer (and others) can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/q/6675454/283366

Comment: Hoo right the " : " damn i didn't think of it. Thank you guys !

Comment: @Phil Yes, I re-opened the question. [The best answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675454/special-characters-in-id-of-html-tags#35748423) had 0 upvotes. Using `getElementById` in this case makes much more sense that fixing the jQuery behavior.