# Jquery window scroll and position fixed sidebar stops working when links contain special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar with some anchors inside of it. Now the user the can either click or scroll down to the desired section, and the sidebar will be position fixed all he way. So as far it works fine but when it comes to anchors with special characters it doesn't work.

So for example I have:

```
<ul>
   <li class="scroll-down-to news">
     <a href="#news">News</a>
   </li>
   <li class="scroll-down-to about">
     <a href="#about">News</a>
   </li>
   <li class="scroll-down-to look-at-1.place">
     <a href="#look-at-1.place">Look at 1.place</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

As soon as I have a link like the `#look-at-1.class` it gets broken and the scroll with the position fixed sidebar doesn't work anymore.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  $(".list").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var formatted = elem_id.replace(/[\. ,:-]+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      elementOffset = $("#" + id).offset().top - 200;
    if (elementOffset < scrollTop) {
      $(".scroll-down-to").removeClass("js-active");
      $(".scroll-down-to." + id).addClass("js-active");
    }
  });
});
```

All I get is an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Does someone know whats wrong here?

Comment: when you console log the id, what does it log ?

Comment: it returns the anchors link -> `#about`etc.

Comment: same for `look-at-1.place` ?

Comment: yes it returns `#look-at-1.place`

Comment: it seems that it doesn't like strings like `look-at-1-place`, it works only with single words `about`, `news` etc :-/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675454/special-characters-in-id-of-html-tags

Comment: Maybe check this answer as it talks about special chars in IDs, even tho '-' should work

Comment: What about removing dots and dashes?